# How to print sqlite3 query result as a matrix on canvas?

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

I want to put the result of an sqlite3 query in the form of matrix and print it on a tk canvas. The query returns three columns of a table from the database. Can anyone help in doing this?

Comment: Anything you want to do on the canvas is probably an option in http://www.nemethi.de/tablelist/tablelist.html.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the canvas, why not use a tktable.  All the work of drawing lines and formatting items into columns is already done.

```
#!/usr/bin/tclsh
# We need these otherwise it will not work
package require sqlite3
package require Tktable

# open database - in this case stockbox.db in the current directory
sqlite3 db stockbox.db

# Set up the titles
set models(0,0) "Model"
set models(0,1) "Width"
set models(0,2) "Length"

# Start with 1 for the title
set rows 1
set cols 3

# Perform query, extract result into models
db eval {SELECT model_id,width, length FROM tbl_model} {
    set models($rows,0) $model_id
    set models($rows,1) $width
    set models($rows,2) $length
    incr rows
}
db close

# Create the table
table .table -variable models -titlerows 1 -width $cols -height 10 -rows $rows -yscrollcommand ".ys set"
scrollbar .ys -command ".table yview"
pack .table .ys -side left -fill y
```